# Kubernetes pod not logging, but containers are logging to the Docker daemon

Tags: logging, kubernetes

I have a pod that is being run as an individual pod created from the API directly and not from kubectl.  I can confirm the only container within the pod is running and it is logging when I go directly to the node and run `docker logs -f <container id>`  but when I do a `kubectl logs -f <pod name>` no logs are outputted.  I've been running Kubernetes for awhile now, and this is the first time I've run into this.  I am running the latest stable version (1.4.x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the container in the pod was set as a TTY enabled container which caused the process inside the container to have a prompt that was blocking any logs from being sent out to the connection kubectl opens up.

Comment: I just had the same issue.  And yep, `tty: false` fixed it for me.